# CaptiveNetwork force popup to show within my app

Tags: ios, iphone, wifi, captivenetwork

I'm trying to use the CaptiveNetwork api to determine if I'm connected to a specific wifi which I know has a captive portal popup...I then need to force the app to show that popup if the user hasn't already authenticated to it.

I see the CaptiveNetwork Apple docs but there are no examples. The following functions seem like the ticket but I can't get them to work: CNMarkPortalOnline CNMarkPortalOffline ... and if they did work I'm not sure how to then get the portal to trigger if offline.

This is where I've started:

```
CFStringRef ssids[1] = { CFSTR("Museum") };
CFArrayRef arr_ssids = CFArrayCreate(NULL, (const void **)ssids, 1, &kCFTypeArrayCallBacks);

if( CNSetSupportedSSIDs((CFArrayRef)arr_ssids))
{
    NSLog(@"Successfully registered supported network SSIDs");
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"Error: Failed to register supported network SSIDs");
}


CFArrayRef myArray = CNCopySupportedInterfaces();

if(CNMarkPortalOnline(CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(myArray, 0))) {


    NSLog(@"portalOnLine");
}

CFArrayRef myArray2 = CNCopySupportedInterfaces();

if(CNMarkPortalOffline(CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(myArray2, 0))) {


    NSLog(@"portalOffLine");
}
```

Best,
jennie

Comment: I tried your code and it seemed to work and register our device with our SSID as expected but I did not get the pop up, the device was able to make requests after the code executed and saw the log @"Successfully registered supported network SSIDs".

Comment: @Jiebe Hi Jennie, Alberto. I am bout to make the same thing, please would you let me know if the user need to select the wifiSSID first in Wifi Settings ? Or it can simply launch the app, and if SSID is not detected by iOS, the user will be alerted "the wifi is not there" ? Brief, do you need to select Wifi first ? Much thanks.

Comment: I put a question here: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/197635/sdk-captivenetwork-reference-must-i-set-wifi-first